# How to use square brackets for math in Java?

Tags: java, math, formula, square-bracket

While converting a mathematical formula to Java, I encountered square brackets (I found them in the formula). I don't know what they mean in mathematics, because I'm no math expert, just a 14-year old hobby-programmer (so I've not reached to these "difficulty-levels" in math in school).

It's obvious that I can't write something like this:

```
double x = [5 / 2] * (3 + 5 * 2);
```

because `[` and `]` are used for arrays.

Therefore, I wonder what to replace them with in order to make Java accept it and interpret it correctly.

Comment: square brackets can be replaced by curved brackets

Comment: @Ogen So they are basically the same?

Comment: precisely my young padawan

Comment: If you don't understand the formula, how can you know whether you're correctly implementing it in Java?

Comment: (this could also be a question on math.se - "What do square brackets mean in a formula?")

Comment: @immibis- It is just for highest priority and hence first evaluation while evaluating a mathematical expression.

Comment: @immibis It's a formula for converting coordinates between different coordinate systems, so I'm going to try it out when it's done.

Comment: Square brackets are sometimes used to represent the floor function; that could be the case in your formula.  (That use is a little dated, going back to Gauss, and most authors nowadays prefer Iverson's `⌊ ⌋` notations.)

Comment: At the age of 14, I was taught to evaluate "square brackets" (`[]`) first, "curly brackets" (`{}`) next, and parentheses (`()`) last. Not so in Java (or programming, in general). When writing in Java, simply use parentheses everywhere, and they will be evaluated from inside to outside.

Comment: Btw, do the two downvotes bother anyone else? This was a genuine question...

Comment: @jrharshath Thanks! And btw, I don't see why this question got downvoted either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove those square brackets and replace them with normal parentheses `()`.

```
double x = (5 / 2) * (3 + 5 * 2);
```

Based on the priority, the first statement to be evaluated will be the square-bracket statement because of **`highest-precedence`** and **`left-to-right associativity`** in solving this particular expression.

Comment: Nit: associativity and precedence don't fully determine order of evaluation: Java's "subexpressions are evaluated left to right" rule is also relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets can replaced by parenthesis. I assume you're aware about BODMAS used for mathematics problem resolution, hence brackets are used for separation and prioritizing operators .

```
double x = (5 / 2) * (3 + 5 * 2);
System.out.println(x);
double y = 5 / 2 * 3 + 5 * 2;
System.out.println(y);
```

above code snippet gives output:-

26.0

16.0